# Update code to use Cocoa Touch framework instead of iOS Universal Framework

Tags: frameworks, ios8, xcode6

With the release of Xcode6, Apple has given a new feature that we can create "Cocoa Touch Framework" from Xcode itself. Earlier we were using iOS Universal Framework. I want to know how we can update our code to use "Cocoa Touch Framework" rather than "iOS Universal Framework".

Answer (score 0):

We have a process that we have put together and many people are using. There are step by step instructions that we have shared on our blog.

You can find them here: https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios8-remix/

Comment: Thanks, but try to avoid one-link-answers. Once you have moved your blog somewhere else, the link will be invalid. Insert some steps into the answer.